# GraphQL query does not update on react router v4 history push

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-router-v4, react-apollo

I would like to implement a basic filtering option in my React web app. I have three components

```
VideoList
--------------------------

Filter    Result 
--------  ----------------
category
```

the `Filter` component and the `Result` component are both children of the `VideoList` component. In the `filter` component when a user clicks on the category, I am pushing a new url, like this `this.props.history.push(`/videos/${category.name}`)`. It seems like my `react-router` settings works correctly and the `VideoList` component gets new category name and successfully passes it to the `Result` component.

```
<Route exact path="/videos" component={VideoList}/>,
<Route exact path="/videos/:category" render={props => <VideoList {...props} />} />,
```

In `VideoLIst` component

`<Result category={category} />`

The `Result` component makes usage of a new category name in its own GraphQL query as follow:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(VIDEOS_QUERY, {
    options: props => { 
      return {
        variables: {
          filterByCategory: props.category ? props.category : null,      
        }
      };
    },
...
```

But, by some unknown to me reasons when pushing new url for the first time `props.data.VideoQuery` (this is return values from graphql server) in the `Result` component gets `undefined`. However, when a user clicks on the `category` second time, the `Result` components renders correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Update your integration part of the apollo client with the below code.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: newLink,
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Switch` instead of Routes with `exact`?

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/videos" component={VideoList} />
  <Route path="/videos/:category" render={props => <VideoList {...props} />} />
</Switch>
```